# jquery, perl, form and serialize command not working IE browser

Tags: jquery

I have this form section with dynamic clone of select drop down menus.

The form are passing the values into the serialize.

```
 var data3 = $("#advance_mode_inputs").serialize();
```

Firefox works but in IE, it isn't working. Any ideas? There were no errors reported by the IE browser.

regards,
Gordon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind,

I discovered that I was missing the `</form>` for this form.

Another question, any good tools to do checks like this?

Comment: W3 or any other HTML validator

Comment: I downloaded and it works for the first page; However, i am also getting html pages by using the $.gets function and this isn't checked... how do i validate those?